# How to set the filterlist to " "

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm wondering if there is a way to clear the filterlist field. I have a clear button in my app and I want it to delete all the 
values in the filterlist field. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you have an `AutoCompleteField`, and you want to clear out all the choices that you originally gave it, in a filtered list?

Comment: Sultan, you should put the "@" symbol before Eugen's name (actually, it's better to write EugenMartynov), so that he gets automatically notified of your comment.  Without that, he won't know that you asked him for follow-up.  Note that I don't have to put that symbol before your name, because this comment is in under your question, so stack overflow knows who to notify.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thanks for your reply. But what do you mean by "halt method"?

Comment: @Sultan BasicFilterList.halt()

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thanks. I tried to make to use it but it didn't work. Have you tired it before?

Comment: @Sultan Sorry, never used. It was just guess. Hope you will find your solution.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thank you for your help :) I hope I will find the solution soon.